# Installing packages and saving the output from apt in a log file

Tags: apt, logs

Whenever we need to install any packages in Ubuntu we install it using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install <package-name>
```

Using redirection as below will save all the logs in a file:

```
sudo apt-get install <package-name> > Log.txt
```

But the above command doesn't show any output in the terminal. Is there any way we can save all the logs in a file and can also see it on terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you have to use `tee` to accomplish that.

```
sudo apt-get install <package-name> | tee Log.txt
```

Comment: Thanks `tee` looks great. One more thing, it overwrites logs for every command. How can we append new logs into the same file using tee because normally I guess we can do it using `>>`

Comment: With `-a` you can look those things up real quick with the `man` command. Which now would be `man tee`

Answer (score 1):

As [Ziazis explains](https://askubuntu.com/a/936014/527764) you can use `tee` to save STDOUT from a command in a file at the same time as it's printed in the terminal, but in this case it might not be needed.

The output is actually logged automatically in `/var/log/apt/term.log` so there's usually no need to create an additional log.